# Kafka Streams Yearly time Window

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

There is a requirement in one of the applications that we are working on is, aggregation to happen on a windowed manner and the windowing size may vary monthly/quarterly/half yearly/yearly.

Kafka streams calendar based timed window supports this and I would like to get more inputs on the performance front to know if it would best suit the need.

1. The memory consumed by the cache to hold the records till the window size.

   Number of records that gets streamed on a daily basis within the window is really high.
   Please suggest can Kafka stream processing be used in this case and how about the resources for the memory management.?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Streams does not store the raw input records per window, but only the current (intermediate) aggregation result. Thus, the window-size is actually irrelevant for the required memory, if you compute an actual aggregation.